# Modify Menu based on Session MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session, razor, menu, controller

I'm not sure how to achieve this, so I would like to have some recommendations about it. What I'm  trying to accomplish is to basically (I'm using pure MVC3.Net) modify the html of the layout page whenever a specific session has started or ended. This is the idea that I had based on the requirement of showing more options to the main menu if the user enters to the details of a project (project is an entity). Furthermore, the options will depend on the type of the user.

After doing a bit of research, I came up with the idea of catching the event of session start, which I would create whenever a project is selected, but Im not sure if I can work it out when the session starts or ends and then modify the html.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can solve your task using dynamic sitemap features from https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider.

And if you dont want to use this provider, I suggest to use BaseViewModel for all viewmodels, and store project status there.
So you can do something like this:

```
@model BaseViewModel(or something derived) 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = ViewBag.Layout;
}

public ActionResult Index()
    {
       if(Model.HasProjectDetails)
       {
        @Html.Partial("_ExtendedNav")
       }
       if(Model.HasSomeExtraProjectDetails)
       {
        @Html.Partial("_MoreExtendedNav")
       }
}
```

But in overall Id suggest to use sitemap provider with https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Dynamic-sitemaps

Comment: Never heard of this SiteMap provider, I'll check it out to see if it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can control the layout of the view from the controller based on the session here is a short example

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = ViewBag.Layout;
}

public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if(Session["one]=="one")
       {
        ViewBag.Layout = "~/Views/Shared/site_1.cshtml";
       }
       if(Session["one"]=="two")
      {
       ViewBag.Layout = "~/Views/Shared/site_2.cshtml";

      }

}
```